# How to calculate efficient binominal coefficient or sum of these coeficients mod value?

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

The task is to write a program, what would calculate the large binominal coefficient:
`n!/m!/(n-m)!` mod value efficient with a program.
As a variant, for the case that this would be simpler, how to calculate sum of sequence of binominal coefficients, like that:
`C(n/m) + C(n/m-1) ... + C (n/1) where C (n/1) = n` obviously, all expression mod value efficient.
Any idea, how to solve it please?

Comment: For binomial coefficient you can use `prod(m+1, n) / (n - m)!` thus saving `m` multiplications.

Comment: What is "mod value"?